# How to calculate the optimal time interval in multiple time series forecasts?

Tags: algorithm, optimization, time-series

First thing first, I am new to the world of statistics.

Problem statement:

I have three predicted time series. These time series represent three independent scores, the sum of which is desired to be minimized over timeslot while selecting it. Length of the timeslot is already provided. I have read that there is confidence based selection of predicted interval for such problems, but I have used LSTM to predict the time series which may restrict me to use that approach, perhaps I think calculating the predicted interval is related to single time series.

e.g: Consider below arrays represent the three predicted time series.

arr1 = [23, 34, 16, 5, 45, 10, 2, 34, 56, 11]

arr2 = [123, 100, 124, 245, 125, 120, 298, 124, 175, 200]

arr3 = [1, 3, 10, 7, 2, 2, 10, 7, 8, 12]

time slot length = 3

As you could see, optimal timeslot for arr1 is [5, 7], for arr2 is [0, 2], and arr3 for is [3, 5], but I need only one timeslot for all three time series.

Questions:

1. Which error paradigm I should employ to select the optimal time slot?
2. I also have given weights(positive real number in [0, 1]) which represents the importance of particular time series in deciding timeslot. How do I employ it in error paradigm?

Comment: To improve your chances of getting an answer, please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) post.

Comment: @jsb Thanks for suggesting, I hope you have read the question. What do you think I should add/remove from the question?